# vbs- Object doesn't support this property or method: objProcess.commandLine

Tags: vbscript

I have the below vbs script which should accept a processname (e.g. Notepad.exe), and then report the relevant details for all processess matching that name.

It works fine on my PC (win 7), but on my server (Windows 2000) I get an error saying that `"Object doesn't support this property or method: objProcess.commandLine"` (line 30)

I'm assuming that it is something to do with windows 2000, as I have it running on Windows 2008 ok. Is there something I need to install / change to make this work?

```
    Option Explicit

dim strComputer
dim objWMIService
dim colProcessList
dim objProcess
dim PName
dim PCommandLine
dim PCLSplit
dim input
dim counter

input = InputBox("Please Enter the Process Name, as shown in Task Manager", "Enter Process Name", , 100, 200)

If input = "" Then    
    WScript.Echo "Canceled"
Else 
    WScript.Echo "You Entered: " & input

    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & input & "'")

    counter = 1
    For Each objProcess in colProcessList
        Wscript.echo counter & ")"
        PName = objProcess.Name
        PCommandLine = objProcess.CommandLine

        PCLSplit = SPLIT(PCommandLine,chr(34))

        Wscript.Echo "Application Name: " & PName & VbCrLf &_
        "Command Line: " & PCLSplit(1) & VbCrLf &_
        "Instance Name: " & PCLSplit(2) & VbCrLf
        counter = 1+1    
    Next

wscript.echo "COMPLETE"

End If

wscript.quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CommandLine Data Type is not available for OS's PRE Win XP...  However, you can simply use some Error handling to avoid any errors from Win2000 systems

Add "On Error Resume Next"
And Check for the Existence of the Chr(34) within the Variable, If not found then you can handle as appropriate or enter your own values...
Also, I fixed the syntax for the counter...  If Counter = 1 + 1 Then it will always equal 2...You want to add 1 to its own value so it then becomes Counter = Counter + 1

```
Option Explicit

dim strComputer
dim objWMIService
dim colProcessList
dim objProcess
dim PName
dim PCommandLine
dim PCLSplit
dim input
dim counter

input = InputBox("Please Enter the Process Name, as shown in Task Manager", "Enter Process Name", , 100, 200)

If input = "" Then    
    WScript.Echo "Canceled"
Else 
    WScript.Echo "You Entered: " & input

    On Error Resume Next

    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = '" & input & "'")

    counter = 1
    For Each objProcess in colProcessList
        Wscript.echo counter & ")"
        PName = objProcess.Name
        PCommandLine = objProcess.CommandLine

        If InStr(1, PCommandLine, Chr(34),1) > 0 Then
            PCLSplit = SPLIT(PCommandLine,chr(34))
        Else
            PCLSplit = Array(vbNullString, "Not Found", "Unknown")
        End If

        Wscript.Echo "Application Name: " & PName & VbCrLf &_
        "Command Line: " & PCLSplit(1) & VbCrLf &_
        "Instance Name: " & PCLSplit(2) & VbCrLf
        counter = counter + 1    
    Next

wscript.echo "COMPLETE"

End If

wscript.quit
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Does this mean that the info I would normally get from the 'CommandLine' property, simply isn't available pre XP. I have multiple instances of the same application, and I need to be able to identify which ones are running, and which aren't. (I have a bigger script which does this, but uses the same code base - so didn't include it here).

Comment: @IGGt This is a toughie as I don't have a PRE XP system to test on.  How would you normally or manually identify this?  Also, as far as whats available via WMI the Scriptomatic 2.0 by the Windows Scripting Guy's would probably be your best resource...  You can download it from here:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12028

Comment: cheers, I'll take a look at that. Normally (on post 2000 systems) I use the above script, and the command line part of it returns a string like 'c:\folder\filename.exe instanceName'. I then split them up and display them (or in the main script check them against a list to see if an application instance is running or not).

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN

> CommandLine
>
> Data type: string
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Command line used to start a specific process, if applicable. **This property is new for Windows XP**.

Comment: Cheers, I had a feeling it would be something like that.